# Show that $W$ is a subspace and find its dimension.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x\in R^n$ be any nonzero vector. Let $W\subset R^{n\times n}$ consist of all matrices A such that $Ax=0$. Show that $W$ is a subspace and find its dimension.

It is trivial to verify that $W$ is a subspace. Since $A_1x=0$ and $A_2x=0$ implies that $(A_1+A_2)x=0$ and $kAx=0$ with $k\in R$.

I know that the dimension of vector space $F^{m\times n}$ of $m\times n$ matrices is $mn$. That is $E_{ij}$ which have a $1$ in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column and a zero everywhere else. When I tried to find the dimension of $W$ defined above, I cannot relate it with the rank of $A$.

This is my first blood on Math stack. Guys please conquer.

Comment: 1. How do you show something's a subspace? (Or have you already done that part?) 2. Your statement "That is $E_{ij}$ which have..." is a little muddled. What you mean is "The set of $nm$ matrices $E_{ij}$ form a basis for ..."; in your case, $m = n$, so it's a set of $n^2$ matrices. But there are many other bases as well. You'll need something different from the $E_{ij}$s to compute the dimension you're looking for. By the way, $A$ is not a single matrix -- there are MANY matrices $A$ in $W$, and they have different ranks...so rank of $A$ isn't a relevant notion for this problem.

Comment: @JohnHughes, thanks for your advice. OP has been updated. Maybe I should not mention the rank here. I wrongly though that the rank have some relation with dimension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For proving $W$ is a subspace, you should also see that $0 \in W$ but it is trivial.

For calculating the dimension, let $T: \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be defined by

$$ TA = Ax \qquad \text{ for } A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $$

Then by the dimension theorem,

$$ \dim(\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}) = \text{nullity}(T) + \text{rank}(T) $$

Note that $x \neq 0$. WLOG assume $x_1 \neq 0$. Then for any fix $k = 1, 2, \ldots, n$, we let
$$A_{k,1} = 1 \text{ and }A_{i,j} = 0 \text{ otherwise}$$

that is, 
\begin{equation*}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \ldots
& 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots
& \vdots \\
1 & 0 & 0
& 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots
& \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots
& 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Then we have 
$$Ax = (0, 0, \ldots, x_1, \ldots, 0)^T = x_1 e_k \neq 0$$

Note that $n$ different such matrices $A$'s are defined. Therefore we have $n$ independent vectors in $R(T)$ and 
$$ \text{rank}(T) = n $$

Therefore,

$$ n^2 = \dim(W) + n $$
$$\dim(W) = n(n-1) $$

Comment: I do not understand the proof of $rank(T)=n$. I think that $rank(T)=dim(x)=n$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes $\text{rank}(T) = n$ because $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$. I just prove this by finding $n$ independent vectors in $R(T)$. You can try to write the $Ax$'s for each of the $A$'s and see this. Note that I actually define $n$ different matrices $A$.

Comment: Edited. Hope it is more clear now. And what if $x = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For showing $W$ is a subspace, there are $3$ conditions to check.  Do you remember what they are?  They should be pretty straightforward to check so it would be better if you told us where you were stuck.

For the dimension: Look at the linear map $R^{n \times n} \to R^n$ given by $M \mapsto Mx$.  First off you should prove that this is linear.  Second, notice that the kernel of this map is exactly $W$.  Do you have a theorem about the dimensions of the kernel and image and domain of a linear map?

Comment: Thanks. I was a newbie at Math and was stuck in the dimension calculation. What do you mean by the last sentence? A theorem? Could you please provide more material so I can catch.

Comment: It's called the [rank nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Comment: I am really enlightened. Many thanks!@Jim